# SqlDataAdapter.Fill() incorrect syntax near "=" C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sqldataadapter

I am getting this error

> Incorrect syntax near "="

I am getting this error on the line

```
sda.Fill(dt);
```

I can't figure out what mistake I have made. I went through many articles but none of them can help me with my problem.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\TECHNOGEEKZ\Desktop\USSv0.1\USSv0.1\USSv0.1\db\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM attachments WHERE idno = " + comboBox1.Text + "", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);

comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "name";
```

Database table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[attachments] 
(
    [Id]       INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [idno]     INT           NULL,
    [name]     VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [location] VARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
```

Can somebody solve this error? Where exactly is the error in this code?

Comment: I think comboBox1.Text is an empty sting.

Comment: @PepitoSh Yes it was empty I just checked.. Thanks a lot it helped!!

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 4):

First, try to return `comboBox1.Text`, to see whether which value it returns. Let say it returns a empty, null value or not an integer number, your query will be wrong.

Second, instead of passing directly `comboBox1.Text` to your SQL query, you should use parameter.

It helps to reduce ridiculous error like you have currently, as well as preventing SQL injection.

Change your `sda` to:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT name FROM attachments WHERE idno = @idNo", con);

sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNo",comboBox1.Text);
```

Comment: *ridiculous* was a bit harsh.

Comment: @EzLo just try to stress it. Once she remember it and apply it, we will reduce number of website having SQL injection, in future :)

Comment: But @Ashwini Nemade. no hurt feeling, please, it's just some experience, for your own good